# Wireless data acquisition for PC

Tags: usb, serial, wireless, data

I’m looking for an off the shelf device to send a serial stream of data (low speed ok) wirelessly to a PC.  I’m guessing the easiest way is through a comm port or USB port.  Distance is less than 25 ft.
I also need to write code to catch the data.  Can anyone suggest some inexpensive off the shelf hardware? Low cost is important in this project.

Comment: It sounds like something like an RS232 to Bluetooth module might be the kind of thing you are looking for. Search eBay for "serial bluetooth module", the HC-05 or HC-06 is one example.

Comment: There is a wireless USB protocol (http://www.usb.org/developers/wusb/) that I've had mixed luck with -- mixed mostly because products that facilitate this seem to have disappeared from the market!!

Answer (score 1):

If your data collection system has a serial output, the least expensive way would be to wire straight across to the PC's serial port. Any terminal emulator program on the PC side could capture the data for you. If there is no serial output, you could bit-bang the data on an output pin. You'll need a level shifter in between to unless your hardware provides the 12v communication level the PC expects.

Easier but slightly more expensive is an HC-06 Bluetooth module such as this [BT2S](https://www.virtuabotix.com/product/bt2s-bluetooth-serial-slave-arduino-versalino-microcontrollers/). It looks to your system like a serial port (connects to your system's serial I and O pins or your bit-bang pin(s)) and transceives via Bluetooth to/from your PC. Again, a general purpose terminal emulator program on the PC can collect the data.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth solution: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9954
WiFi solution: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9954

Comment: Some explanation along with the links would be welcome; we generally discourage link-only answers. Also, the two links are identical.